# Yii framework, after submiting the form text fields are not updated in database

Tags: mysql, yii

I am pretty new with MVC and Yii framework, therefore there is a good chance that my question is pretty stupid. If so, accept my appologies in advance.

I want to have a form in my admin section of the website, where, user can post some content. I followed the tutorial for sample blog however it seems that the content added to the fields that are defined as text in the database (textarea in my form) don't get updated after submitting the form (everything else works fine). here is the sql statement for my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_show` (
   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `presentation` text,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `fk_tbl_show_tbl_season1` (`tbl_season_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

I used Gii to make my Model and CRUD, I only add here the parts that might be related:

On my controller:

```
    public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Show;

    if(isset($_POST['Show']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Show'];
        if($model->save())
                    {
                        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
                    }   
    }
    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
```

and my _form.php:

```
<div class="form">

 <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
 'id'=>'show-form',
 'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
  )); ?>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'presentation'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'presentation',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'presentation'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
</div>

    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

    </div><!-- form -->
```

Model Rules:

```
return array(
    array('id, presentation', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
);
```

I don't get why only the text content don't get updated, they appear as null in the database.

Thank you in advance,
Cheers,
Mahsa

Comment: How do you have the 'safe' list defined in your model rules?

Comment: `array('id, title, presentation', 'safe', 'on'=>'search')`

Comment: You have this for the 'search' scenario, but you are initializing your model with no scenario. You need to add a new safe list, for 'insert,update' scenario.

Comment: is status getting saved properly?

Comment: Now nothing happens when I submit my form! no data gets added to the database!

Comment: @bool.dev yes, that one was getting saved before just now that nothing works...

Comment: if you are using @Pentium10's suggestion then you have to also declare your objects with that scenario, i.e: `$model = new Show('insert');`

Comment: @bool.dev update and insert is automatically handled by the framework, it's not necessarily to declare like this, but indeed helps the programmer.

Comment: @Pentium10 oh didn't know, thanks much for clearing that up, but then i don't think it's necessary to add attributes to a separate safe rule, other than for the search scenario, because anyway gii's auto generated code declares only safe on search rule, am i right?

Comment: The confuse here and all the time is that required attributes are always treated safe, and that's why is not standard to declare and insert,update safe list. But you need them.

Comment: @Pentium10 alright, that clears it up for me, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to make the attribute safe . Add this to your `Show` models validation rules

```
array('presentation','safe')
```

Comment: Now I have a new problem, when I submit the form no rows get added to the database! And I don't get any errors, I almost didn't change anything... What can cause this?

Comment: @MahsaTeimourikia can you paste your model rules?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem for the form not submitting correctly, I add it here in case anybody has the same problem:

I'd overwritten the beforeSave, but I wanted to complete it later so it wasn't returing anything:

```
protected function beforeSave() {
        if(parent::beforeSave())
        {
            if($this->isNewRecord)
            {
               //things that should be added by the system
            }
        }

    }
```

After commenting this everything works fine. Also as you guys recommended I added the fields that didn't have validation to the safe rule.

Answer (score -2):

try this ..

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Show;

    if(isset($_POST['Show']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Show'];

        $save = $model->save(false);      // write like this...
        if($save)
                    {
                        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
                    }   
    }
    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
```

hope it will work for you..

Comment: whats the problem in this..who can down vote to this answer..i think he did not read the question..

Comment: $save = $model->save(false); will be always true, because you are bypassing validation